# How can I repeat a potentially failed update of Ubuntu 18?

Tags: 20.04, r

I am new to Ubuntu but I have a good coding backgroud. I tried to update my Ubuntu 18 machine to the latest, Ubuntu 20.04. I followed a tutorial I found online. But I think the update was not succesful because I got stuck and had to power off and start back my computer. On running the command **lsb_release -a**, I got an output on the terminal indicating that the system is now updated.But I think this update was not successful because there was no R installation anymore on my computer and I tried in vain to reinstall R following this [R tutorial](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-20-04/). What can I do to do the installation properly and subsequently install the latest version of R?

```
(base) cha@xxx-SYS-7039A-I:~$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
(base) cha@xxx-SYS-7039A-I:~$
```

Comment: Poweroff during a release-upgrade is among the worst things you can do to your system. There is no way to predict what's broken on your system (if anything), since we don't know exactly which package install you interrupted (if any). "*Tried in vain*" is not promising for your current system, but without seeing actual input and output of what you tried, you're asking us to speculate. The safest and simplest solution is to backup your data and then fresh-install 20.04. It's often the fastest solution for many users, too.

Comment: Ubuntu Core 18 is a very different system (a different product) to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS so reinstall is required.  Ubuntu releases using the *year* format are *snap* only, where as the *year.month* releases are *deb* package based, but can also use *snaps*. On *snap* based systems, like Ubuntu Core 18, the upgrade process doesn't impact applications (*snaps* are the same for all releases; only the base system is upgraded). Ubuntu Core 18 is a different product to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I think you'll find you were on 18.04 and not a 18 product.

Comment: You should never power-off; did SysRq commads direct to the kernel not work?  If they didn't work that would have meant you had a *kernel panic* which is normally very evident on the screen (unless hardware failed for other reasons like power spike etc which you should get checked out).  Even if a system is unresponsive, exploring via terminal is always a good way before every considering touching a power button.. How long did you leave it?  I've had *release-upgrades* take 18-24 hours on complex systems lacking resources.. and it's common for hour+ to pass without change on screen...